# If I don't want a PHP framework, what am I asking for and what's out there?

Tags: php, frameworks, libraries, toolkit

I've spent a lot of time reviewing the various PHP frameworks.  I found Yii the best of the best, but the more I got into it, the less comfortable I felt with an architecture that takes a lot of responsibility (and transparency) away from the developer.

I'm looking for (a library?  a toolkit?) that will give me the benefit of consistent documentation and functionality without forcing me to us its definition of MVC.  I looked into FatFree, but its GPL.

Is there anything out there that people are using that they could point me to?

Edit: Thanks all for helping me clarify!  I think I'm looking for something closer to Zend that is more a collection of methods that allows me to define my own structure but call upon a toolkit whenever I need certain functionality.

Zend seems too monolithic.  And I can certainly roll my own, but I'm wondering if there is simply something out there that has a community and peer support that I am overlooking.

Comment: PHP itself gives you "consistent documentation and functionality".  What makes you think you don't want to just code in PHP?  There must be some other level of benefit beyond what you cited ... what do you want?

Comment: And what's your objection to GPL?

Comment: You don't have to distribute source code if you just run GPL PHP code on the server.  You would only have potential obligations if you distributed code.

Comment: When you say "...without forcing me to us its definition of MVC" does that mean you want a non-MVC framework/library/toolkit?

Comment: And we're thinking of more questions as fast as we can!

Comment: Sounds like you want a Component Framework like Zend or EZComponents... but at the same time it sounds like youll also find them unusable because you didnt write the components :-)

Comment: Thanks so much folks!  I've edited my OP to reflect my clarifications.

Comment: @prodigitalson 'Components' seems to be on the right track.

Comment: @Vsack: I can appreciate your comment about Zend being monolithic, but if you have no intention of using the full stack then it really isnt all that bad. However, if you are planning on using individual components it can be an annoying chore to make sure you've also grabbed all the dependencies.

Comment: The whole point of a framework, or even a library for that matter, is to delegate responsibilities to the framework and trade transparency for faster development times (note that it's all still perfectly transparent, it's just PHP). If you don't feel comfortable with that, your only choice is probably to write your own.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Ruby

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [Flourish](http://flourishlib.com). I used it for several projects, and found it quite good. It describes itself as an 'Unframework', which might be what you are looking for.

Regarding licensing issues: as noted above, the project's license doesn't really matter unless you want to redistribute it. In which case, I think you will find Flourish's license quite suitable: it's [MIT](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/MIT/).

Comment: Definitely going to check it out tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you all, I was pointed into the right search direction and came across several answers to my own question:

What I am/was looking for are **PHP Components** that tend to be more loosely coupled together but are peer supported more as a collection rather than a tool.

Apache Zeta Components (formerly EZComponents) is in the incubator right now.
Symfony is building out and supporting components of their own.
Zend we mentioned above but may prove cumbersome due to dependencies.
And of course I completely forgot about PEAR...

Symfony intrigues me mostly because it looks like they are dumping support into it, whereas all I ever heard about it was that it was a very top-heavy framework.

Comment: Well the compoonents are used to create the Symfony2 Full stack. You are probably referring to Symfony 1.4 which is much more coupled though very extensible.